# Class template parameter default value

Tags: c++

There is a class template definition for `time_point` template class from standard C++ library:

```
template<
    class Clock,
    class Duration = typename Clock::duration
> class time_point;
```

Can someone please explain me the line:

```
class Duration = typename Clock::duration
```

?
I know that we are defining a default value for the second template parameter `Duration` but the thing i don't understand is the `::duration` part after `Clock` type name. Should't it be just:

```
class Duration = typename Clock
```

?

Comment: Clock::duration looks like a member class. In C++ you can embed classes inside classes. This is extensively used in stl containers, just check the reference of std::vector.

Answer (score 2):

Marek has already explain almost everything in his answer, this one is to improve it.

`typename` is need to tell compiler "look, duration is nested in `Clock` and depend on
it, you have to resolve `Clock` first and then deduce `Clock::duration`"

here there's a stupid example of a dependent type, is not meant to be used in production code.

```
template<typename T>
class MyBase
{
public:
   using UnderlyingType = T;
   // ...
   double foo() { return 5.5; }
};

class MyIntChild : public MyBase<int>{};

class MyDoubleChild : public MyBase<double>{};

template<typename T, typename D = typename T::UnderlyingType>
D makeFoo(T& t)
{
   return t.foo();
}

MyIntChild a;
makeFoo<MyIntChild>(); // return 5 because return type is int;
```

Comment: Where can i find the `using alias = type_name` syntax documentation? The official C++ site [link](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/using_declaration) doesn't provide  any info about using "=" operator in using declaration...

Comment: @Daros911 https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias

Answer (score 1):

This would use the type of the `Clock`:

```
class Duration = typename Clock
```

However, the `Duration` is a type different from `Clock`. There is a [named requirement *Clock*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Clock). Among other things it specifies that a Clock should have a `duration` member alias.

A member alias is something like this:

```
 struct my_clock {
      using duration = int;
 };
```

So when you instantiate a `time_point<my_clock>`, the second template parameter becomes `my_clock::duration`. The keyword `typename` is needed because it is a dependent name. You need to assure the compiler that `Clock::duration` really is a type.

Answer (score 0):

This is called dependent type.

Note class can contain `typedef` (`using =` ) inside. `Clock::duration` is just referring to this type definition which is expected inside type passed as first argument.

Now `typename` is needed to explain to compiler that depending symbol must be a type (it could be constant).

Take a look on some clock [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/system_clock) it has `typedef` for duration:

[std::chrono::system_clock - cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/system_clock)

> #### Member types
>
> | Member type | Definition |
> | --- | --- |
> | `rep` | signed arithmetic type representing the number of ticks in the clock's duration |
> | `period` | a [std::ratio](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/ratio/ratio) type representing the tick period of the clock, in seconds |
> | `duration` | [std::chrono::duration](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration)<rep, period>, capable of representing negative durations |
> | `time_point` | [std::chrono::time_point](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/time_point)<std::chrono::system_clock> |

Comment: Where can i find the `using alias = type_name` syntax documentation? The official C++ site [link](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/using_declaration) doesn't provide  any info about using "=" operator in using declaration...

Comment: `typedef int value_type` and `using value_type = int` are equivalent. Second one is available since `C++11`.